# Customizing TraceSource to avoid creating TraceEventCache

Tags: c#, .net, trace, tracesource

My project have many classes. Each class use TraceSource for logging. I don't want to use TraceEventCache while logging. Basically the answer for it is we can tell the listner to do not  write TraceEventCache using TraceOptions (CallStack, ProcessID etc). That means TraceSource already has the TraceEventCache. So my question is does TraceData and TraceEvent methods of TraceSource class create TraceEventCache for every call ? Or is just single object created by the framework per thread and just used in TraceSource class.

Answer (score 2):

Your question hinges on how you think the TraceSource class is written.  Better than speculating, you can check the reference source code, both [Microsoft](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1478852/is-there-a-way-to-view-net-framework-library-source-code-online)'s and [Mono's](https://github.com/mosa/Mono-Class-Libraries/blob/master/mcs/class/System/System.Diagnostics/TraceEventCache.cs).

Anyhow, in there you can see this is called for each call to Trace(...)

```
TraceEventCache manager = new TraceEventCache();
```

As far as I can tell, the only way in which it behaves like a cache is that call stack (and a few other) properties defer determining their values until called and if called twice, return the value from a local variable. This is because things like CallStack are slow. Otherwise, TraceEventCache is just a collection of boring properties. It isn't a cache like the ASP.NET intrinsic Cache.

To improve performance, just don't tell any of your trace listeners to output the call stack or any thing else that might be slow.